# Expected value and variance of a set of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ are $n$ independent r.v.s, with the same probability distribution and with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Let $$
\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}
$$
I know the expected value will be $\mu$ and variance will be $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, but I'm not sure on how to prove it. Thank you in advance :)

Edit: I'm sorry. I'm aware of how to expand $E(\bar{X})$ and $Var(\bar{X})$ using the formulae. The part that is tripping me up the most is the last step, i.e. why $\frac{1}{n}(E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_n))$ can be simplified as E($\bar{X}$), and similarly for variance

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{var}\left( \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {n^2} \operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots +X_n) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {n^2} \left( \operatorname{var}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{var}(X_n) \right) \\[8pt]
& \text{and so on.} \\[10pt]
\operatorname E\left( \overline X \right) = {} & \operatorname E\left( \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 n \left( \operatorname E(X_1+\cdots+X_n) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 n \left( \operatorname E(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname E(X_n) \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry! I have clarified my confusion in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E(\bar X)&= \mathbb E\left(\frac{\sum _{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\right)=\frac1n\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E(X_i)=\frac1n\cdot n\mathbb E(X_i)=\mathbb E(X_i)=\mu \\
\text{Var}(\bar X)&= \text{Var}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\text{Var}(X_i)=\frac1{n^2}\cdot n\sigma ^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}
\end{align*}

Edit: for any random variables $A$ and $B$, $$\mathbb E(A+B)=\mathbb E(A)+\mathbb E(B)$$
If $A$ and $B$ are independent, $$\text{Var}(A+B)=\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)$$

Comment: Sorry! I have clarified my confusion in the edit.

Comment: @appleline made an edit. does this answer your question?

Comment: So does that mean $\mu =E(X_1)+E(X_2)+...E(X_n)$  and $\sigma^2 = Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)+...+ Var(X_n)$ are always true for all real number of $n$ ??

Comment: 5201314, why not $n \mu$ ? or $n \sigma^2$  ? btw the 2nd equation is true if independent but only if as well?

Comment: I thought you defined $\mu =\mathbb E(X_1)=\mathbb E(X_2)=\cdots =\mathbb E(X_n)$ in your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For any constant $c$, $E(cX)=cE(X)$. (An explanation at the end.)

So then
$$\begin{align}
E(\bar{X})=E\left(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}\right)
&=E\left(\frac{X_1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{X_n}{n}\right)\\
&=E\left(\frac{X_1}{n}\right)+\cdots+E\left(\frac{X_n}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}E(X_1)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}E\left(X_n\right)&\text{using }c=\frac1n\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\mu+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\mu\\
&=\frac{n}{n}\mu=\mu\\
\end{align}$$

And with variance, it's similar. But the constant relation is $\operatorname{Var}(cX)=c^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$. That squaring of $c$ puts $\frac{1}{n^2}$ as the coefficient in the penultimate line, leaving a coefficient $\frac{n}{n^2}$ against the $\sigma^2$.

---

Why does $E(cX)=cE(X)$? Well, what is the definition of $E$? It should be something like: $$\sum_x x\cdot P(X=x)$$ or an integral version of that: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\cdot p(x)\,dx$$ So $E(cx)$ is $$\sum_x cx\cdot P(X=x)\quad\text{or}\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}} cx\cdot p(x)\,dx$$ and the $c$ can be factored out of the sum or of the integral:
$$c\sum_x x\cdot P(X=x)\quad\text{or}\quad c\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\cdot p(x)\,dx$$
$$c\cdot E(x)$$

Comment: I'm sorry. Why is the expected value of any X = the mean $\mu$ ? Similarly for variance

Comment: @appleline "Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ are $n$ independent r.v.s, with the same probability distribution and with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$." that's what you wrote?

Comment: @appleline OK, $E(X)$ is defined as a sum or an integral as posted here. And $\mu$ is just _defined_ to equal $E(X)$. When a distribution is presented with $\mu$ ahead of time, it is a requirement that should you calculate $E(X)$, it equals $\mu$.